# Multirow/column and figure inside table/tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, multirow, multicolumn

I'm having some issues with my current try to code something that I aim to look like:

[image]

I am in no way an experienced LaTeX writer, so I would love to take inputs on every part of the code, even if its not really connected to the main issue!

My code currently looks like: (The logo-picure is just an example, I used http://media02.hongkiat.com/psd-text-svg/logo-example.jpg)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow,bigstrut}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=0.2in]{geometry}


\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[inner sep=0pt] (tab){%
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{tabular}{l|l|ll} \cline{2-4}
  \multirow{2}[2]{*}[-1mm]{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{Logo}}  &{\Large Header} &\multicolumn{1}{l}{{\large author:}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{{name}}\\ 
                                                                                         \cline{2-4}  & {\Large Receptor} & Page 1/n  &  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{date}} \\ 
\rowcolor{Gray}\textbf{} &\textbf{} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{}}\\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\multirow{5}{*}{iggujhjhhhjhvjhvjhvvvhjvhbkjbk}}                \\
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{}                                 \\
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{}                                 \\
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{}                                 \\
\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{}                               \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

};
\node[draw=black,inner sep=20pt, rounded corners=10pt, line width=1pt,
fit=(tab.north west) (tab.north east) (tab.south east) (tab.south west)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Just a few side questions:
Is there any way to get the current date in Swedish? I am doing it manually at the moment.

Is there anyway to automatically set current page/total pages? For example, page 1/5 for page 1 out of 5 in total.

Is there any way to have a pre-specified total table width and height?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! On this site, one question per question is preferred. 'Side questions' should be, well, questions. Pass `swedish` as an option to the class and load the `babel` package. Then use `today`. `pageslts` for the numbering. `tabularx` for the tabular width. (Not sure this would make any kind of sense for height - please explain!)

Comment: Ah, I apologise for the question part, it was things i noticed when i changed the original code. I will definitely try out the babel package ad also pageslts. Problem with the "big cell" of the tabular is that it either doesnt make new lines within my multirow+column, or it mis-formats the whole table. Ill try to get back with an illustration for how it looks, and also: thanks alot for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a starting point with `tcolorbox` and `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=0.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\tcbset{%
  mybox/.style={
    colback=white,
% You may use the tcolorbox width to set the width of your table using X columns (but it's only one of the n possibilities
    width=15cm,
    },
  }
  
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
 
\usepackage{blindtext}% <--- for testing purpose only

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[mybox]
\begin{tblr}{colspec={lXlX},
  hlines,
  vline{1-X,Z}={solid},
  vspan=even,
  hspan=minimal,
  row{Z}={m},
  cell{1}{1}={r=2}{m},
  cell{Z}{1}={c=4}{m}
  }
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image} & Header & Author: & Name\\
    & Receptor & Page \thepage/\pageref{LastPage} & \today\\
\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-a} Some text 
\blindtext &&&\\
\end{tblr}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]